# Outputting flavor text depending on inputted strings

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, array, combinatorics

I have this program that takes two strings from the user, stores them in `mixArray`, then "mixes" them with `mixItUp()` and outputs a bit of flavor text, depending on the combination. Duplicate combinations (red-blue, blue-red) also give the same outcome.

I've gotten to a nested switch statement that's miles shorter than my previous tries, but I'm trying figure out if there's a more optimal, or readable method to do this, since I intend to scale it up.

```js
mixItUp() {
  this.mixArray.sort();            // Sorts the array
  switch (this.mixArray[0]) {      // Goes through the first object
    case "blue":
      switch (this.mixArray[1]) {  // Goes through the second if the first is "blue"
        case "green":
          console.log("bf");
          break;
        case "purple":
          console.log("bg");
          break;
        case "yellow":
          console.log("bp");
          break;
        default:
          console.log("??");
          break;
      }
      break;
    case "green":     // If [0] is "green"...
      switch (this.mixArray[1]) {
        case "purple":
          console.log("fg");
          break;
        case "yellow":
          console.log("fp");
          break;
        default:
          console.log("??");
          break;
      }
      break;
    case "purple":     // If [0] is "purple"...
      switch (this.mixArray[1]) {
        case "yellow":
          console.log("gp");
          break;
        default:
          console.log("??");
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context - what is the purpose of this code? See [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), where you will find advice for titling your question, too.

Comment: The simplest fix I can think of would be to define the output strings in a single `const` object like so : ```const colors = {
  "red" : {
    "red" : "a",
    "blue" : "b",
    "green" : "c"
  },
  "green" : {
    "red" : "x",
    "blue" : "y",
    "green" : "z"
   }
};``` then you can access them like this ```str["red"]["blue"]```. I'd also recommend you make the function return a string which you then print in the program, rather than printing the output directly from the function; this makes it more flexible and easier to adapt/modify later.

Comment: Thanks, @cliesens! Didn't even think of using a json object, but this works wonderfully and is way easier to read and change. Kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this could be simplified with a small lookup table and then concatenating strings. Using a table as simple as:

```
const lookup = {
  blue: 'b',
  green: 'f',
  purple: 'g',
  yellow: 'p'
};
```

we can then lookup the color values and concatenate them together. Combined with a simple check to make sure the color is valid and the 2 colors aren't the same, and it seems to produce the same result.

Here's the full function:

```
mixItUp: function() {
  this.mixArray.sort();
  const lookup = {
    blue: 'b',
    green: 'f',
    purple: 'g',
    yellow: 'p'
  };

  let mix;
  const color1 = lookup[this.mixArray[0]];
  const color2 = lookup[this.mixArray[1]];

  if (color1 && color2 && (color1 !== color2)) {
    mix = `${color1}${color2}`;
  } else {
    mix = '??';
  }

  return mix;
}
```

And here it is in action:

```js
function createMix(color1, color2) {
  return {
    mixArray: [color1, color2],
    mixItUp: function() {
      this.mixArray.sort();
      const lookup = {
        blue: 'b',
        green: 'f',
        purple: 'g',
        yellow: 'p'
      };

      let mix;
      const color1 = lookup[this.mixArray[0]];
      const color2 = lookup[this.mixArray[1]];
      
      if (color1 && color2 && (color1 !== color2)) {
        mix = `${color1}${color2}`;
      } else {
        mix = '??';
      }

      return mix;
    }
  }
}


// Handle the form
const form = document.getElementById('mixitup');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const color1 = document.getElementById('color1').value;
  const color2 = document.getElementById('color2').value;

  const mixedArray = createMix(color1, color2)
  console.log(mixedArray.mixItUp())
})
```

```html
<form id="mixitup">
  <select id="color1">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <select id="color2">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Mix it up!">
</form>
```